# CONNECT HTTP method via C#

Tags: c#, http, sockets

good morning
I am C# programmer , I have got a problem

I tried to open socket to get an HTTP connection and read the page as a stream of bytes
and all was right , 
for example, to get the home page of google via a C# Socket,
the steps that I followed are :

1.Opening a stream and connect to google server :

```
Socket skt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
skt.Connect("www.google.com", 80);
```

2.preparing the request and put it in bytes array :

```
string hdrs = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    + "Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
byte[] req_as_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hdrs);
```

3.Sending HTTP request :

```
skt.Send(req_as_bytes);
```

4.Receiving the response :

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 200]; // 200 kilo bytes
int t = skt.Receive(data);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data,0,t));
```

but when I changed the http method from [GET] to [CONNECT] , 
the respone would be empty ! or no data were received from the server
the new request was :

```
string hdrs = "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    + "Host: www.google.com:443\r\n"
    + "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
```

can any one help me?

the full code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket skt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    skt.Connect("www.google.com", 443);
    string hdrs = "CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        + "Host: www.google.com:443\r\n"
        + "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    byte[] req_as_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hdrs);
    skt.Send(req_as_bytes);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 200]; // 200 kilo bytes
    int t = skt.Receive(data);
    Trace.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, t);
    skt.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    skt.Close();
}
```

thank you ...
Mhamad

Comment: Do you know what `CONNECT` does? Do you know what to do or expect next? HTTP isn't the most easy-to-learn protocol when you're trying to learn sockets.

Comment: What do you expect `CONNECT` will do? Why do you think it will work for google.com?

Comment: it works for any website support https,

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to implement an HTTPS server, you need to read the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

BTW, it's already implemented in .NET: [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Comment: `Socket` implements TCP which is a transport layer protocol. HTTP / HTTPS are application layer protocols which sit on top of TCP. If you want to use `Socket`, you will have to implement HTTP / HTTPS from the RFCs. This will not be easy - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.Connect("www.google.com", **80**);

string hdrs = "CONNECT www.google.com:**443** HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    + "Host: www.google.com:443\r\n"
    + "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
```

80 - 443 conflict !

if you using 443 port ? Must be using .NET 4.0 FRAMEWORK- SSLSTREAM class..